# extract strings from patterned string list and convert it into dataFrame in python

Tags: python, string, extract, formatted

I have a list which contains patterned string like this:

```
['"Bandcamp" (2014)\t\t\t\t\ttv-mini-series',
'"ByMySide" (2012){The Happening (#1.3)}\t\t\t\t\ttwitter-hashtag-in-title',
'"Elmira" (2014)\t\t\t\t\telmira-new-york',
'"Elmira" (2014){The Happening (#1.3)}\t\t\tfriend',
...]
```

Now, I am trying to extract sub-strings from each line, and make them into a data frame like:

```
Movie    Year Keyword
Bandcamp 2014 tv-mini-series
ByMySide 2012 twitter-hashtag-in-title
Elmira   2014 elmira-new-york
Elmira   2014 friend
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
>>> a
['"Bandcamp" (2014)\t\t\t\t\ttv-mini-series', '"ByMySide" (2012){The Happening (#1.3)}\t\t\t\t\ttwitter-hashtag-in-title', '"Elmira" (2014)\t\t\t\t\telmira-new-york', '"Elmira" (2014){The Happening (#1.3)}\t\t\tfriend']
>>> data = []
>>> for x in a:
...     data.append(re.findall("\"(\w+)\" \((\d+)\).*\t{2,5}(\S+)", x)[0])
... 
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Movie', 'Year', 'Keyword'])
      Movie  Year                   Keyword
0  Bandcamp  2014            tv-mini-series
1  ByMySide  2012  twitter-hashtag-in-title
2    Elmira  2014           elmira-new-york
3    Elmira  2014                    friend
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's amazing. It seems the code does not work on these: ['"$#*! My Dad Says" (2010) {Code Ed (#1.4)}\t\tcode','"#iGOTSHAPES" (2012) {Zander Hardy Feat. Asha Rae - Spending Time}\tperiod-in-title','"#1 Single" (2006)\t\t\t\t\tnumber-in-title'] Would you mind let me know what's the problem with it? Thanks a lot.